# Is it true that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{Var(Y_n)}{n}<\infty$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

> Suppose that $\{X_n\}$ is an i.i.d. sequence of random variables with $E|X_1|<\infty$.Define $Y_n=X_nI_{\{|X_n|<n\}}$ for all $n\geq1$. Is it true that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{Var(Y_n)}{n}<\infty$?

I believe NO is the answer. Intuitively, as $n\to\infty$, $Var(Y_n)\to Var(X_1)=\sigma^2$ so basically after some $n$ we would be having the series as $\sum_{k=n}^\infty\dfrac{\sigma^2}{n}=\infty$.

I also checked on Wolfram Alpha taking $X_n$ to be a standard normal randm variable. $Var(Y_n)=2.5063$ for all $n\geq10$ which proves divergence.

Comment: What is your source?

Comment: The question came in a semester exam. Surprisingly the question said, "Prove that the sum converges". This held me suspicious. Might have been a printing error.

Comment: The correct conclusion is probably that the series $\sum\limits_n\frac1{n^2}\mathrm{Var}(Y_n)$ converges (note the $n$ squared).

Comment: @Did Probably, because then this boils down to SLLN.

Comment: Not really. The solution is a play with expectations and sums and indicator functions, *which is useful to prove a SLLN*, but the SLLN does not help to prove the series converges.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have guessed, the answer is NO in general. And a single counter example is enough: take $\{X_n\}$ i.i.d. uniform $(0,1)$ then $|X_n|< n$ for all $n\geq 1$ so that
$$
Y_n=X_n\implies\text{Var}{Y_n}=\text{Var}{X_n}=\frac{1}{12}\implies\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\text{Var}{Y_n}}{n}=\frac{1}{12}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n}=\infty.
$$